# 4in6 tunneling software for Windows

Tags: windows, vpn, ipv6, tunneling, ipv4

I have a VM running Windows 2008 R2, and I need this VM to connect to a remote site using VPN.
The VPN software does not support Windows 2008 R2 or any other 64 bit operating system, so I can't install it on my VM.

But then I have another VM running Windows 2008 SP2 x86, and this is connected to remote site through the VPN software. Between the two VM's I have an ipv6 network. I cannot communicate from the R2 VM to the SP2 VM using ipv4 because the VPN client does not allow split-tunneling.

I was therefore hoping that I could use a 4in6 tunneler to route the ipv4 traffic from my first VM, through the second VM, and finally to the remote network.

I have googled quite a lot, but have not succeeded in finding tunneler software for Windows that supports 4in6. Does such an application exist, or do I need to develop it myself?

Any other suggestions on how to solve this problem would also be appreciated!

[Update]
I still haven't figured out how to solve this.
Any news on ipv6 compatible tunnelers?

Answer (score 0):

An idea, not really a solution:

Try L2TP or a 4in4 tunneling protocol (GRE?), and then run that over IPv6.

It seems to me that most of the 6in4 tunneling issues was more about setting up manageable routing and less about the protocol specification of the tunnel. The "protocol" in "protocol" encapsulation seems to be done pretty much the same way, it was always the management piece or the gui configuration piece that tripped people up.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! How can i run a 4in4 tunnel over IPv6? Not sure how to accomplish that...